# Are there studies on the distracting effects of "inline auto complete" features?

Tags: autocomplete, chrome

There are few features I dislike more than "inline autocomplete", which is what Chrome does when you type in the address bar.

Are there studies on the distracting effect of those features?

From personal experience, I sometimes lose my train of thought because Chrome changed what I was typing to some random correction.

Side note: The Chromium dev team refuses to provide a way to turn this off, cf. issue [#334300](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334300#c43), from 2014.

Answer (score 1):

It's not distracting, it's helpful. Every usability test I have seen shows increase in task completion and finding your choice.

Here is a good article about the patterns for different uses.

http://baymard.com/blog/autocomplete-design

Comment: Ah, but you're only talking about autocomplete features; those are great. But what about _inline_ autocompletion? On the link you provided (great examples btw), none of the suggestboxes change the contents of their textbox until the user picks a suggestion.

Comment: Like this? http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#simple-combo